# Seaborn fixed lineplot height

Tags: plot, seaborn

If I use seaborn lineplot, they height of the graph is fixed to the largest y value in the graph. Is there a way to set that height manually?
I need to have a fixed height standards for all plots in order for them to become compareable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
ax.set_ylim(-1,30)
```